# Splitting Text and Integer from values in a Drop Down List

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-access, drop-down-menu, split

I have a Drop down list with values:

Dogs - £100

Cats - £30

etc

I am trying to split the string "Dogs" and the amount "£100" and store each one in a different fields in access database.

I know a way of doing it with IF statements but is there a command of doing it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try This:

```
String [] str=drpdownList.SelectedItem.ToString().Split('-');
String str1=str[0].Trim();
String str2=str[1].Trim();
```